# Trouble in starting kafka producer using java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hi I'm getting trouble in starting kafka producer using java. please help me if u know the proper solution. below is the code i've used. I've went throgh various solutions on statck overflow. and tried some of them but they didn't solved the issue.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

public class KafkaProducerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "9092");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        //Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("TestTopic", "Message from java");
            producer.send(producerRecord);
        }
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

The Exception i got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:434)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at com.innominds.producer.KafkaProducerClass.main(KafkaProducerClass.java:21)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid url in bootstrap.servers: 9092
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:408)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Try `properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");` or if not working on your localhost, then provide the actual address of at least one of the brokers.

Answer (score 0):

`properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "9092");`

9092 is not a valid DNS name in your network.

You must provide a valid IP or host along with the port you want to connect to

---

I would suggest using a higher level library such as Vertx or Quarkus or Spring for simpler configuration options